# (Pygame) Player not moving

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner, so sorry if this is a dumb mistake, but the player in my game is not moving.
I was pretty sure that this is correct, because this is what I was taught in the game that I used for my computer programming camp (the game for the camp worked perfectly fine) but this one just doesn't work.

```
# pygame import
import pygame
from pygame import *
pygame.init()

# game window
game_window_width = 800
game_window_height = 600

# colour
red = 255, 0, 0
orange = 255, 128, 0
yellow = 255, 255, 0
green = 0, 255, 0
darkGreen = 0, 128, 0
blue = 0, 0, 255
darkBlue = 0, 0, 128
purple = 200, 0, 255
pink = 255, 60, 203
white = 255, 255, 255
black = 0, 0, 0
grey = 128, 128, 128
brown = 100, 80, 30
color = 0

# game setup
game_window = display.set_mode((game_window_width, game_window_height))
display.set_caption('gameTemplate')

print('outside game loop')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_over = False

# game loop
while not game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            game_over = True

    print('inside game loop')

    # game background
    backgroundIMG = pygame.image.load('crossyRoadBG.png')
    backgroundIMG = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundIMG, (game_window_width, game_window_height))
    game_window.blit(backgroundIMG, (0, 0))

    #man
    manR = 80
    manX = 220
    manY = 520
    manSpeed = 30
    draw.rect(game_window, brown, (manX, manY, manR, manR))
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            manX += manSpeed
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            manX -= manSpeed

    # frame
    clock.tick(30)
    # update
    display.update()

# game exit
pygame.quit()
```

Any help?

Comment: you have mess in code - key events `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` should be inside loop `for event in pygame.event.get():`

Comment: you set `manX = 220` `manY = 520` inside loop `while not game_over` so in every loop it set again the same position. And it can't move

Comment: You could load background and transform it before loop - you don't have to load again and again the same image. In loop you may have to only display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not problem with PyCharm but with mess in code. You have elements in wrong places. You check `keys` outside `for event` loop. You set position `manX = 220`, `manY = 520` inside loop so you move player again and again to the same place - and it can't move.

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

# --- constants ---

# game window
game_window_width = 800
game_window_height = 600

# colour
red = 255, 0, 0
orange = 255, 128, 0
yellow = 255, 255, 0
green = 0, 255, 0
darkGreen = 0, 128, 0
blue = 0, 0, 255
darkBlue = 0, 0, 128
purple = 200, 0, 255
pink = 255, 60, 203
white = 255, 255, 255
black = 0, 0, 0
grey = 128, 128, 128
brown = 100, 80, 30
color = 0

# --- classes ---

# empty

# --- functions ---

# empty

# --- main ---

print('outside game loop')

pygame.init()

# game setup
game_window = display.set_mode((game_window_width, game_window_height))
display.set_caption('gameTemplate')

# - objects -

# game background
backgroundIMG = pygame.image.load('crossyRoadBG.png')
backgroundIMG = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundIMG, (game_window_width, game_window_height))

#man
manR = 80
manX = 220
manY = 520
manSpeed = 30

# - loop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_over = False

# game loop
while not game_over:

    print('inside game loop')

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            game_over = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                manX += manSpeed
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                manX -= manSpeed

    # - moves/collisions/updates (without draws) -
    
    # empty
    
    # - draws (without moves/collisions/updates) -
    
    game_window.blit(backgroundIMG, (0, 0))

    draw.rect(game_window, brown, (manX, manY, manR, manR))

    # frame
    clock.tick(30)
    # update
    display.update()

# - exit -

pygame.quit()
```

---

**BTW:** next time you can use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what program is doing.

---

**BTW:** using current method with events you will have to press again and again to move object. You may need [pygame.key.get_pressed()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)